# In Jmeter, Can it generate script in the body every time it loop?

Tags: jmeter

I have a script that i send to the API like this.

```
[
    {
        "sku": "${SKU1}",
        "qty": "${Quantity1}"
    }
]
```

I want every time it loop it will add a script like this and send it.

```
[
    {
        "sku": "${SKU1}",
        "qty": "${Quantity1}"
    },
    {
        "sku": "${SKU2}",
        "qty": "${Quantity2}"
    }
]
```

Is it possible?

I want every time it loop it will auto add the script on the body data.
and get the SKU and Qty on my mountbank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the following [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code:

```
def payload = []
1.upto(vars.getIteration(), {
    payload.add([sku: vars.get('SKU' + it), qty: vars.get('Quantity' + it)])
})

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

Refer generated value as `${payload}` where required.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)